# Run/Test Application as "Guest User"

Tags: c#, debugging, privileges

Is it possible to debug or test my C#/VB/F#/... Application as user with 'low privileges' (e.g. as guest user)?
I would like to see how it would work if the user running my application is not an administrator.

Do I have to create a guest or "low-level privileges" account to test this, or does a plugin (for VS) or a command exist, which simulates such a thing?

---

tl;dr: I need to test the opposite of *Run as Administrator*

---

**EDIT №1:** I do *not* really create a new (guest) account for this purpose, as it always takes so much drive space (creating user directories, settings, desktops etc.) ....

Comment: [Run the process as a user with low privileges.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903629/how-do-i-run-a-program-from-command-prompt-as-a-different-user-and-as-an-admin)

Comment: [Powershell equivalent](http://blogs.technet.com/b/benshy/archive/2012/06/04/using-a-powershell-script-to-run-as-a-different-user-amp-elevate-the-process.aspx) then place in [Build Definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181286(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @KiwiPiet i think he's asking if there's a way  to facilitate that process with VS