# How do I run a MULTIPLE programs from command prompt as a different user and as an admin

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, admin

Basically the below question, except I would like to launch multiple programs with a single command. Can the syntax be expanded to achieve this? The solution is offered by Coruscate5.

[How do I run a program from command prompt as a different user and as an admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903629/how-do-i-run-a-program-from-command-prompt-as-a-different-user-and-as-an-admin/40097313#40097313)

Syntax for a single program is:
runas /user:DOMAIN\USER2 /savecred "powershell -c start-process -FilePath "'C:\PATH\TO\YOUR\EXECUTABLE.EXE'" -verb runAs"

What would be the syntax for launching EXECUTABLE.EXE, and EXECUTABLE2.EXE, and EXECUTABLE3.EXE? Note: the same credentials are to be used for all programs.

Edit: Command Prompt will prompt for a password, "Enter the password for DOMAIN\USER2:". The password should preferably need to be entered only once. Alternatively, once per executable (with no other commands required inbetween).

Comment: why do you use powershell to run windows executable file? You cen run it directly by Runas command. To run multiple executables, create a batch file with multiple commands (each line each command) and start such batch

Comment: @user2956477 UAC elevation

Comment: Powershell bypass UAC???

Answer (score 1):

runas /user:username "cmd /c start EXECUTABLE1.EXE & start EXECUTABLE2.EXE"